# Have a DataGrid Appear under a textbox

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

What I want is for a datagrid to appear under a textbox when the user starts.  Once focus is lost from the textbox the datagrid disappears.  I am having a hard time format it so does not screw up the rest of the windows formatting.

Before you ask about using a list box, I need multiple columns and the user should be able to reorder the list.

Comment: You probably want to use Adorner and DataGrid as its child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more idea. Bind the visibility of the DataGrid to a property from your ViewModel. Initially you can set the Visibility to Visible.

Next you can use the Interactivity on the textbox's LostFocus event to change the Visibility to Hidden/Collapsed.

The following is an example

```
    <TextBox Text="Test">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataGridVisibilityCommand}" CommandParameter="Collapsed"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
    <DataGrid Visibility="{Binding DataGridVisibility}"/>
```

add the namespace

```
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

to your window/usercontrol and add the necessary dll references.